# Como alterar um link <a> de acordo com um <select>?

Tags: jquery

> Estou criando uma tabela de preços para meu site, e preciso que quando a pessoa alterar o ciclo de pagamento, seja alterado o link `<a>` *(CONTRATAR)* para ir ao carrinho.

Exemplo: Se a pessoa selecionar o ciclo **Mensal**, o link mude para:

`http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?produto=1&periodo=mensal`

Se a pessoa escolher **Trimestral**, o link mude para:

`http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?produto=1&periodo=trimestral`

Se a pessoa escolher **Semestral**, o link mude para:

`http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?produto=1&periodo=semestral`

E se a pessoa escolher **Anual**, o link mude para:

`http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?produto=1&periodo=anual`

> **EXEMPLO NO** [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreBR/23met8eu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que complicaram demais, o select deve lhe fornecer o valor que você realmente precisa, que é a periodicidade, e o preço é que deve vir como um data atribute, e apenas o valor sem formatação...

Recomendo algo assim:

**HTML:** (apenas as modificações)

Mudar o atributo `value` para a periodicidade e criar o atributo `data-preco` com o preço:

```
                <select class="select-ciclos" name="select">
                    <option value="mensal" selected="selected" data-preco="6,99">Mensal</option>
                    <option value="trimestral" data-preco="28,77">Trimestral -4%</option>
                    <option value="semestral" data-preco="54,14">Semestral -8%</option>
                    <option value="anual" data-preco="99,99">Anual -16%</option>
                </select>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(".select-ciclos").heapbox({
    'onChange': function (value, src) {
        $(src).closest('.pricing-column').find('.trans').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 250, function () {
            $(this).children('span').html($(src).find("option:selected").attr("data-preco"));
            if (value == 'mensal') var ciclo = '/mês';
            if (value == 'anual') var ciclo = '/ano';
            $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/<\/span>.*/g, '</span>' + (ciclo ? ciclo : '')) );
            $(this).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 250)
        })
        var elementolink = $(src).closest('.pricing-column').find('.pricing-footer a');
        var link = elementolink.attr("href");
        elementolink.attr("href", link.replace(/periodo\=(.+?)(&|$)/g, 'periodo=' + value + '&').replace(/&$/g, ''));
    }
});
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/z04dp5ds/)

Comment: Seu Fiddle tem 2 problemas: `1°` na primeira tabela não muda a URL do link (Isso eu já arrumei: http://jsfiddle.net/z04dp5ds/1/). `2°` Eu utilizei o código no value justamente por isso, porque quando você muda o ciclo de pagamento continua o nome "/mês" ao lado do preço (em branco).

Comment: Exemplo - código que eu estava usando: `<option value="<sup>R$</sup><span>6,99</span>/mês"`

Comment: Seu código ficou excepcional, porém, o único problema é esse "/mês, /ano, etc."

Comment: @AlexandreLopes No primeiro link eu modifiquei propositalmente a ordem dos parâmetros (de: `carrinho.php?produto=1&periodo=mensal` para `carrinho.php?periodo=mensal&produto=1`) para testar a regex de substituição, e acabo de testar no IE, FF e CH e todos fazem a substituição corretamente, tem certeza que não esta mudando? que navegador você usa? Quanto ao /mês e /ano realmente não tinha percebido, acabo de editar a reposta com uma possível solução, o jsfiddle também foi editado.

Comment: Agora a 1° tabela tá funcionando normal :D, é porque você esqueceu de colocar `produto=` no seu primeiro fiddle. Só que agora tem um probleminha @Jader os nomes "/mês, /ano, etc." devem ficar depois de `</span>` (6,99</span>/mês) ex: `<div class="trans"><sup>R$</sup><span>6,99</span>/mês</div>`. No seu exemplo fica tudo junto (6,99/mês): `<div class="trans"><sup>R$</sup><span>6,99/mês</span></div>`

Comment: Veja como tem que ficar quando estiver estilizado: http://i.imgur.com/4I4KDIw.png | @Jader você poderia colocar um `data-ciclo=""` e dentro dele o valor "/mês, /ano, etc.". Você poderia fazer com que esses nomes "/mês, /ano, etc." aparecessem depois do `</span>` ou então criar um próprio `<span>` pra colocar o nome dentro. Obrigado Jader! ;)

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Retirei o /mês do data-preco e usei `if value == mensal/anual` para substituir o final do html, sem ter que criar mais um atributo data...

Comment: Mas não vai ficar bom! Rsrs, tem que ser o nome mês e não mensal. Muito obrigado pela força!

Comment: @AlexandreLopes analise bem o código antes de comentar... E veja funcionando no JSfiddle...

Comment: oops! Me desculpe! rsrsr eu olhei só o HTML. lol

Comment: LOL, ficou muito louco bitchu! Vlw cara, merece melhor resposta! :D

Answer (score 4):

Cara fiz umas alterações no seu [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23met8eu/3/) para funcionar da uma olhada lá.
Achei um pouco confuso porque você ja estava utilizando o value dos options dos combos para controlar a escrita do valor, por isso tive que criar um atributo nos options chamado "**data-opt**" com os valores {M,T,S,A}. Outra alteração que tive que fazer foi colocar id nos links e em cada select criei um atributo **data-link** para fazer a correspondência de cada combo com o seu respectivo link.

Não foi o jeito mais correto de fazer mais esta funcionando.

Comment: Ficou muito bom, porém, esqueci de mencionar uma coisa... Cada tabela dessa é um produto diferente, ou seja, 3 tabelas diferentes. Então tem que fazer uma alteração nesse jQuery. Ex: `http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?produto=1&periodo=mensal` e `http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?produto=2&periodo=mensal` e `http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?produto=3&periodo=mensal`

Comment: Alterei o link do Fiddle la na resposta, criei mais um atributo data-produto no combo, então para cada produto vc tem que alimentar esse atributo.

Comment: Olha isso: http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreBR/23met8eu/5/ fiz algumas alterações no HTML que você esqueceu. Estavam todos como `produto1`

Comment: Parece que ficou perfeito, vou fazer alguns testes, se tudo ocorrer bem, venho aqui e dou como melhor resposta. :D Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$(".select-ciclos").heapbox({
'onChange':function(value,src){

    var mostrador = $(src).closest('.pricing-column').find('.trans');
    var val = value;
    mostrador.animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 250, function () {
        if (val == "<sup>R$</sup><span>6,99</span>/mês")
        {
        $("#cont").attr("href", "http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?produto=1&periodo=mensal");
        }
        else if (val == "<sup>R$</sup><span>28,77</span>")
        {
        $("#cont").attr("href", "http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?periodo=trimestral");
        }
        else if (val == "<sup>R$</sup><span>54,14</span>")
        {
        $("#cont").attr("href", "http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?produto=1&periodo=semestral");
        }
        else if (val == "<sup>R$</sup><span>99,99</span>/ano")
        {
        $("#cont").attr("href", "http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?produto=1&periodo=anual");
        }
        mostrador.html(val);
        mostrador.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 250)
    })
    }
});


$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".select-ciclos").heapbox();
 });
```

Tambem tem que alterar o html do link "CONTRATAR", adicionando um id:

```
<a href="http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?periodo=mensal" id="cont">
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23met8eu/6/)**

Comment: Cada tabela dessa é um produto diferente, ou seja, 3 tabelas diferentes. Então tem que fazer uma alteração nesse jQuery. Ex: `http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?produto=1&periodo=mensal` e `http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?produto=2&periodo=mensal` e `http://meusite.com/carrinho.php?produto=3&periodo=mensal`